# Delete records based on dates

Tags: sql-server

I have a database "DB" and I want to delete records from table "MyRecords" which are of future ("RecordDates" which are more than today just to avoid date change on system) and less than x no. of days from today.

That "x" may vary. Moreover, I want to execute same type of command with month and year also.

I am using SQL Server and C#.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To delete records which are in the future and less than `n` days in the future you could use T-SQL such as this:

```
    DELETE FROM DB.table WHERE 
    (date > GETDATE() AND date <  DATEADD(day, 5, GETDATE()));
```

In this case `n` is 5.

You can see all the arguments to `DATEADD()` at [DATEADD (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx)

Comment: how to do it like, less than 30days in the past? writing -30 should work? its not working for me

Comment: DELETE FROM Table  
WHERE 
TABDate > DATEADD(day, -30, GETDATE()) 
and TABDate < GETDATE()

Answer (score 1):

This query will delete all records that are later than today's date, but less than 30 days in the future.  You could replace "30" with a variable so you could determine how many days in the future to delete.

```
DELETE FROM Table 
WHERE
TABDate > GETDATE() and TABDate < DATEADD(day, 30, GETDATE())
```

**UPDATE**

To delete all records less than 30 days in the past, you would change the query to look like this:

```
DELETE FROM Table 
WHERE
TABDate > DATEADD(day, -30, GETDATE()) AND TABDate < GETDATE()
```

Also note that all these examples are calling `GETDATE()` which also has a time component as well as a date, so care must be taken in that anytime you see a statement like `< GETDATE()` you are not just deleting records with a date before, say, 2011-09-29, you are deleting all records with a date before '2011-09-29 17:30'. So be aware of that if you table dates contain times as well.

Comment: how to do it like, less than 30days in the past? writing -30 should work? its not working for me.

Comment: so what if I want to delete the records just on date basis, but not on time basis. Is there a way?

Answer (score -1):

You can use the query `DELETE FROM DB.table WHERE date > now()` or `WHERE date > unix_timestamp()`, depending on how you are storing your dates. (i.e. date-time vs. timestamp).