# how do I create a stored procedure to delete all records in a table prior to a specific date?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

I need to create a stored procedure that will clear our log file after a certain amount of time back from the current date.

I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7603817/delete-records-based-on-dates) but I'm not familiar enough with tsql to adjust it.

```
    USE SuburbanPortal;
    GO

    CREATE PROCEDURE sp_ClearWebLogTable

    DELETE FROM Web.Log WHERE 
        (date > GETDATE() AND date <  DATEADD(day, 5, GETDATE()));
    GO
```

I did adjust it for my table and database but I need to clear the log, daily, of anything more than a month old.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: In Sql server, you should avoid prefixing your stored procedures with "sp_". http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd172115(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I need to clear the log, daily, of anything more than a month old.

```
DELETE 
FROM Web.Log 
WHERE DateCol <= DATEADD(Month, -1, GetDate())
```

Where `DateCol` is your Date Column

Comment: @ErocM, yes looks fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE FROM Web.Log 
WHERE date <  DATEADD(day, -30, GETDATE());
```

This would delete records over 30 days old.